# Weblogic 10.3 WebService one way SSL HTTP 401: unauthorized

Tags: web-services, ssl, weblogic-10.x

I am stuck with a web service HTTP 401 issue for last two days. Would really appreciate if somebody could give me some direction.

Background

I have developed a webservice which is supposed to do a one way SSL Authentication using weblogic ant commands jwsc and clientgen. I deloped the same as an HTTP service and the same was working properly with the client getting appropriate response.

After this I converted the service to work for a 1 way SSL based on the oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13713/transport.htm#g244821). After the client was generated I changed the service class to https and correct port number, created a truststore using the InstallCert.java from google labs.

Issue
When I tested the above code I am getting the following exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
 [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
 [java]     at $Proxy29.sayHelloWorld(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at examples.webservices.simple_client.Main.callServer(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at examples.webservices.simple_client.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

After loads of google searching I figured how to debug SOAP messages on client side using the `<jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.debug=ssl"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerify=true"/>`

In the output I can see that my server certificate is getting properly authenticated (based on my understanding from various google search results due to the below output

```
    Found trusted certificate:
     [java] [
     [java] [
     [java]   Version: V1
     [java]   Subject: CN=myserver, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY, O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, ST=MyState, C=US
     [java]   Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
     [java]
     [java]   Key:  Sun RSA public key, 512 bits
     [java]   modulus: 11399037646943714373129589413160891986565558044118796140794648360486617578069478083040335022051356380275876221883739208839702905668066595828725571636353511
     [java]   public exponent: 65537
     [java]   Validity: [From: Tue Oct 11 05:46:19 EDT 2011,
     [java]                To: Mon Oct 12 05:46:19 EDT 2026]
     [java]   Issuer: CN=CertGenCAB, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY, O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, ST=MyState, C=US
     [java]   SerialNumber: [    55a93b5e 2866f87c 4d24e2a3 eb4fe6da]
     [java]
     [java] ]
     [java]   Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
     [java]   Signature:
     [java] 0000: 2A 8C EF C6 93 59 A8 0B   59 CD 28 08 7C D5 EC 50  *....Y..Y.(....P
     [java] 0010: B1 31 00 CA 67 DB DE 45   4D B5 40 A8 48 2D 58 5C  .1..g..EM.@.H-X\
     [java] 0020: 04 6E 50 7B 58 C5 14 D7   FD 89 BA C3 18 DC A9 BC  .nP.X...........
     [java] 0030: 33 4A ED EC 35 51 CB 0F   88 BD 0B FC 99 35 1C 7B  3J..5Q.......5..
     [java]
     [java] ]
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
     [java] *** ServerHelloDone
     [java] *** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 70
     [java] SESSION KEYGEN:
     [java] PreMaster Secret:
     [java] 0000: 03 01 4E 55 6E B6 7D F3   1A 95 EC 23 1A 26 A1 F4  ..NUn......#.&..
     [java] 0010: CB 7D 77 0A E2 87 09 34   C9 CD A2 F3 34 5C 7F E8  ..w....4....4\..
     [java] 0020: D1 35 D7 5E BB 1A 13 2F   06 55 72 C5 2A 43 FD ED  .5.^.../.Ur.*C..
     [java] CONNECTION KEYGEN:
     [java] Client Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 92 E3 75 F1   3C 19 4F 5F B1 DE 38 BE  R.....u.<.O_..8.
     [java] 0010: 43 13 D3 0A D8 C0 0D 87   8F 82 32 58 07 1B 09 91  C.........2X....
     [java] Server Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 29 8A F0 E1   31 85 01 D0 B7 6F CC AC  R...)...1....o..
     [java] 0010: 1E C0 F3 69 5C 19 01 C5   05 96 5D 61 ED 34 DE B0  ...i\.....]a.4..
     [java] Master Secret:
 [java] 0000: 2A AC FE C3 23 DC C8 4C   B3 43 52 9A C3 AD 6C 7D  *...#..L.CR...l.
     [java] 0010: 86 64 06 C7 71 7B 0A C2   41 2D D8 85 80 C7 09 2C  .d..q...A-.....,
     [java] 0020: 8D 4B BF BE D7 6A 14 E0   FD 71 7C 42 33 9E E9 3E  .K...j...q.B3..>
     [java] Client MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: C7 C4 4B B0 17 63 EF 15   49 10 41 C9 8E F5 4D B8  ..K..c..I.A...M.
     [java] Server MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: 43 D5 66 32 E6 8D 85 5F   4A 59 4E 22 E2 2D 63 9B  C.f2..._JYN".-c.
     [java] Client write key:
     [java] 0000: C7 A0 5E 3C 95 7D 5B C1   76 58 33 50 32 9F 32 60  ..^<..[.vX3P2.2`
     [java] Server write key:
     [java] 0000: 8E C1 C7 DE A4 46 89 4D   CB 27 19 98 20 59 69 9E  .....F.M.'.. Yi.
     [java] ... no IV used for this cipher
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
     [java] *** Finished
     [java] verify_data:  { 177, 168, 133, 8, 117, 184, 224, 201, 35, 12, 96, 25 }
     [java] ***
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] *** Finished
     [java] verify_data:  { 202, 0, 249, 55, 208, 218, 164, 49, 228, 244, 138, 164 }
     [java] ***
     [java] %% Cached client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 225
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 175
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 3040
     [java] main, called close()
     [java] main, called closeInternal(true)
     [java] main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
     [java] Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
     [java] Allow legacy hello messages: true
     [java] Is initial handshake: true
     [java] Is secure renegotiation: false
     [java] %% Client cached [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
     [java] %% Try resuming [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] from port 56321
     [java] *** ClientHello, TLSv1
     [java] RandomCookie:  GMT: 1376573079 bytes = { 81, 111, 75, 50, 149, 29, 122, 231, 125, 64, 236, 168, 67, 7, 127, 120, 207, 8, 204, 91, 43, 124, 235, 162, 123, 13, 168, 6 }
[java] Session ID:  {202, 36, 120, 65, 56, 38, 121, 89, 214, 122, 192, 105, 176, 215, 37, 182}
     [java] Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
     [java] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
     [java] ***
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 97
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 58
     [java] *** ServerHello, TLSv1
     [java] RandomCookie:  GMT: 1376573079 bytes = { 255, 58, 121, 2, 103, 75, 164, 168, 47, 33, 30, 118, 219, 155, 5, 87, 78, 50, 248, 87, 55, 98, 140, 75, 1, 34, 94, 8 }
     [java] Session ID:  {202, 36, 120, 65, 56, 38, 121, 89, 214, 122, 192, 105, 176, 215, 37, 182}
     [java] Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     [java] Compression Method: 0
     [java] ***
     [java] Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
     [java] CONNECTION KEYGEN:
     [java] Client Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 51 6F 4B 32   95 1D 7A E7 7D 40 EC A8  R...QoK2..z..@..
     [java] 0010: 43 07 7F 78 CF 08 CC 5B   2B 7C EB A2 7B 0D A8 06  C..x...[+.......
     [java] Server Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 FF 3A 79 02   67 4B A4 A8 2F 21 1E 76  R....:y.gK../!.v
     [java] 0010: DB 9B 05 57 4E 32 F8 57   37 62 8C 4B 01 22 5E 08  ...WN2.W7b.K."^.
     [java] Master Secret:
     [java] 0000: 2A AC FE C3 23 DC C8 4C   B3 43 52 9A C3 AD 6C 7D  *...#..L.CR...l.
     [java] 0010: 86 64 06 C7 71 7B 0A C2   41 2D D8 85 80 C7 09 2C  .d..q...A-.....,
     [java] 0020: 8D 4B BF BE D7 6A 14 E0   FD 71 7C 42 33 9E E9 3E  .K...j...q.B3..>
     [java] Client MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: E9 45 08 20 F4 70 E3 F0   B7 EF CB 17 A3 D0 F2 28  .E. .p.........(
     [java] Server MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: 12 5D 3C 63 FE FA FA AC   DC 31 0E C5 AE 52 71 2C  .]<c.....1...Rq,
     [java] Client write key:
     [java] 0000: CE E5 02 F1 A4 EA 87 B3   C7 AF 35 89 DD 3E BD 64  ..........5..>.d
     [java] Server write key:
     [java] 0000: 6E 02 D3 5C A7 3F C5 57   D7 B7 84 CD 8D 4A 17 2C  n..\.?.W.....J.,
     [java] ... no IV used for this cipher
     [java] %% Server resumed [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] *** Finished
     [java] verify_data:  { 253, 116, 209, 250, 88, 31, 151, 15, 134, 162, 94, 55 }
     [java] ***
[java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 225
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 175
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 3040
     [java] main, called close()
     [java] main, called closeInternal(true)
     [java] main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
     [java] the wsdl location is https://myserver:myport/HelloWorldImpl/HelloWorldService?WSDL
     [java] the ports is {https://myserver:myport}HelloWorldPortTypePort
     [java] Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
     [java] Allow legacy hello messages: true
     [java] Is initial handshake: true
     [java] Is secure renegotiation: false
     [java] %% Client cached [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
     [java] %% Try resuming [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] from port 56322
     [java] *** ClientHello, TLSv1
     [java] RandomCookie:  GMT: 1376573079 bytes = { 110, 65, 69, 188, 135, 246, 1, 160, 40, 124, 7, 13, 57, 253, 194, 185, 195, 172, 61, 188, 32, 74, 61, 241, 66, 54, 12, 11 }
     [java] Session ID:  {202, 36, 120, 65, 56, 38, 121, 89, 214, 122, 192, 105, 176, 215, 37, 182}
     [java] Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
     [java] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
     [java] ***
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 97
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 58
     [java] *** ServerHello, TLSv1
     [java] RandomCookie:  GMT: 1376573079 bytes = { 62, 17, 208, 2, 106, 161, 176, 178, 192, 167, 106, 98, 252, 176, 9, 52, 142, 121, 171, 228, 11, 115, 9, 179, 2, 28, 133, 193 }
     [java] Session ID:  {202, 36, 120, 65, 56, 38, 121, 89, 214, 122, 192, 105, 176, 215, 37, 182}
     [java] Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
     [java] Compression Method: 0
     [java] ***
     [java] Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
     [java] CONNECTION KEYGEN:
     [java] Client Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 6E 41 45 BC   87 F6 01 A0 28 7C 07 0D  R...nAE.....(...
     [java] 0010: 39 FD C2 B9 C3 AC 3D BC   20 4A 3D F1 42 36 0C 0B  9.....=. J=.B6..
     [java] Server Nonce:
     [java] 0000: 52 0D D7 97 3E 11 D0 02   6A A1 B0 B2 C0 A7 6A 62  R...>...j.....jb
     [java] 0010: FC B0 09 34 8E 79 AB E4   0B 73 09 B3 02 1C 85 C1  ...4.y...s......
[java] Master Secret:
     [java] 0000: 2A AC FE C3 23 DC C8 4C   B3 43 52 9A C3 AD 6C 7D  *...#..L.CR...l.
     [java] 0010: 86 64 06 C7 71 7B 0A C2   41 2D D8 85 80 C7 09 2C  .d..q...A-.....,
     [java] 0020: 8D 4B BF BE D7 6A 14 E0   FD 71 7C 42 33 9E E9 3E  .K...j...q.B3..>
     [java] Client MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: FC B9 1E 90 2C A4 A2 2F   34 9B F2 FB F5 FD 16 35  ....,../4......5
     [java] Server MAC write Secret:
     [java] 0000: 0D 31 04 6F CE 64 64 8F   5E C0 62 2C 4C 87 BC 7C  .1.o.dd.^.b,L...
     [java] Client write key:
     [java] 0000: B6 21 C1 68 57 93 BB E1   CF 66 6B CC 91 FA C2 24  .!.hW....fk....$
     [java] Server write key:
     [java] 0000: 82 82 6D 40 AD 98 98 27   29 38 C1 DC D0 2B 1C DC  ..m@...')8...+..
     [java] ... no IV used for this cipher
     [java] %% Server resumed [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] *** Finished
     [java] verify_data:  { 118, 17, 113, 93, 80, 136, 119, 75, 181, 180, 92, 119 }
     [java] ***
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
     [java] *** Finished
     [java] verify_data:  { 161, 172, 242, 50, 208, 52, 88, 200, 8, 141, 79, 241 }
     [java] ***
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 338
     [java] main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 242
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 227
     [java] main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 300
     [java] Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
     [java]     at $Proxy29.sayHelloWorld(Unknown Source)
```

In my webservice the authentication policy that I am using is `policy:Wssp1.2-2007-Https.xml.`

What I understand is that my request is being rejected from server side. How to debug or identify this? Can anybody please help me in understanding what is happening here.

Thanks in Advance
Paddy

update -2

Hi,

Please find the policy in WSDL below.

```
<wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="Wssp1.2-2007-Https.xml">
- <ns1:TransportBinding xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
- <wsp:Policy>
- <ns1:TransportToken>
- <wsp:Policy>
  <ns1:HttpsToken /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns1:TransportToken>
- <ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
- <wsp:Policy>
  <ns1:Basic256 /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
- <ns1:Layout>
- <wsp:Policy>
  <ns1:Lax /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns1:Layout>
  <ns1:IncludeTimestamp /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns1:TransportBinding>
  </wsp:Policy>
```

Update 3 -

I tried to remove the policy {@Policy} and try using SSL without any policy spec. Still I am getting the same error. I added SSL debug to my weblogic server. This is the log that I am seeingon server side. The client side exception is same.

```
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write ALERT, offset = 0, length = 2>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <close(): 339812160>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.removeContext(ctx): 1651138619>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <339812160 closed by last read, readRecord returned 0>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <close(): 339812160>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.removeContext(ctx): 1651138619>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Filtering JSSE SSLSocket>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.addContext(ctx): 705673280>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLSocket will  be Muxing>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 received HANDSHAKE>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ClientHello>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm MD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 58>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC, offset = 0, length = 1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 16>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 received CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 received HANDSHAKE>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Finished>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.findContext(sock): 212226998>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <activateNoRegister()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLFilterImpl.activate(): activated: 865292526 510369659>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read(offset=0, length=4080)>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 349>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read databufferLen 349>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read A returns 349>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read(offset=349, length=3731)>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <434381551 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 226>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read databufferLen 226>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read A returns 226>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read(offset=575, length=3505)>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns false 1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 Rethrowing InterruptedIOException>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.findContext(sock): 212226998>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <activateNoRegister()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLFilterImpl.activate(): activated: 865292526 1247045377>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 read(offset=575, length=3505)>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns false 1>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <610789119 Rethrowing InterruptedIOException>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 197>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 6, length = 1518>
<Aug 18, 2013 2:40:45 PM EDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <NEW ALERT with Severity: WARNING, Type: 0
java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.closeWriteHandler(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at javax.net.ssl.impl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.closeSocket(SocketMuxer.java:463)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.closeSocket(SocketMuxer.java:444)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.cleanupSocket(SocketMuxer.java:831)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverExceptionAndCleanup(SocketMuxer.java:788)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverEndOfStream(SocketMuxer.java:716)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:904)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:854)
        at weblogic.socket.PosixSocketMuxer.processSockets(PosixSocketMuxer.java:130)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the policy is requiring basic autentication , and you are not sending the Auth Basic Header. Could you print your policy?.
It's not a problem with SSL.

Comment: Please explain it properly.For better understanding of users.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the policy from WSDL file to my question. Can you please take a look. I am not sure how to check if Auth Basic header is going out on my request or not. Doing all this for first time. Can you please tell me how to check the same. Thanks

Comment: I tried without any policy. Still getting the same exception. SO I guess it has nothing to do with policy. I Have added the server side log also on my main query. Not sure what is trying is right! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem. I did not need the @Policy annotation. Once I commented it out. My webservice was still secure since I had a https url but the token and user name password authentications never kicked in.

Thanks for the help.
Paddy